# Как заставить квадрат двигаться быстрее?

Tags: javascript

Согласно скрипта имеем квадрат, который перемещается по странице при нажатии стрелочек (верх, вниз, вправо, влево) на клавиатуре. Как сделать так, что бы при комбинации на клавиатуре шифт + стрелочка (верх, вниз, влево, вправо) квадрат начинал двигаться еще быстрее?

```
<body>
    <div id="element"></div>

    <script>
       
        let div = document.querySelector("#element");
        let distance = 10;

        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
            switch (e.code) {
                case "ArrowLeft":
                    moveLeft(div, distance);
                    break;
                case "ArrowRight":
                    moveRight(div, distance);
                    break;
                case "ArrowUp":
                    moveUp(div, distance);
                    break;
                case "ArrowDown":
                    moveDown(div, distance);
                    break;
            }
        });

        function moveUp(element, distance) {
            let top = getComputedStyle(element).top;
            element.style.top = parseInt(top) - distance + "px";
        }

        function moveDown(element, distance) {
            let top = getComputedStyle(element).top;
            element.style.top = parseInt(top) + distance + "px";
        }

        function moveLeft(element, distance) {
            let left = getComputedStyle(element).left;
            element.style.left = parseInt(left) - distance + "px";
        }

        function moveRight(element, distance) {
            let left = getComputedStyle(element).left;
            element.style.left = parseInt(left) + distance + "px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Другими словами - "Как определить что стрелка была нажата вместе с Шифтом? ". Из вопроса надо убрать все лишнее.

Comment: исправил описание

Comment: скорость - это дистанция пройденная за время. Так как время ты не можешь изменить, меняй дистанцию.

Comment: да, при изменении дистанции (let distance = 10) на 20 скорость увеличивается. Теперь мне нужно навесить обработчик на distance, что бы при нажатии шфит + стрелочка значение переменной менялось на 20 ?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под _нужно навесить обработчик на distance_? Тебе надо просто передавать `distance+speedUp`  если нажата клавиша шифт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#element');
const step = 10;

const getPath = (distance, speed, direction) => {
  const path = distance * speed;
  if (direction === 'left' || direction === 'up') {
    return path * -1;
  }
  return path;
};

const getCoord = (direction) => {
  switch (direction) {
    case 'left':
    case 'right':
      return 'left';
    case 'up':
    case 'down':
      return 'top';
    default:
      throw new Error('getCoord - Invalid direction: ', direction);
  }
};

const move = (target, direction, speedMultiplier) => {
  const coord = getCoord(direction);
  const currentStyles = getComputedStyle(target);
  target.style[coord] =
    parseInt(currentStyles[coord]) +
    getPath(step * speedMultiplier, 1, direction);
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
  if (ev.code.includes('Arrow')) {
    const direction = ev.code.slice(5).toLowerCase();

    if (ev.shiftKey) {
      move(div, direction, 3);
    } else {
      move(div, direction, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#element {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```